# python 3.6 windows: retrieving the clipboard CF_HTML format

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, clipboard, clipboarddata

I want to copy some rich text, modify its source code (changing some tags and text, using regex and/or beautifulsoup) and send it back to the clipboard. I'm looking for the easiest way to do that.

I tried win32clipboard, but it [doesn't support the `CF_HTML` format](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32clipboard__GetClipboardData_meth.html) ([windows clipboard contains many formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx)).

So I'm looking for a module that could help me to get this format:
if the CF_HTML clipboard format contains HTML, store it in that variable, do some operation, then send it back. (Optionally: and do other stuff on other clipboard formats)

Here is a Linux equivalent of what I'm looking for. It retrieves the HTML source, when there's some in the clipboard ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427704/how-can-i-edit-the-source-of-html-in-the-clipboard/427723))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
print (gtk.Clipboard().wait_for_contents('text/html')).data
```

**Edit1**: There is a work around with pywin32 using [this script](https://gist.github.com/Erreinion/6691093/b2e91a7abf92ac08dce6da9060c99c627c993472). But is there a module able to do that directly (if CF_HTML contains data, get it, and send it back)?

Answer (score 1):

The Edit1 solution seems to be actually the best.

1. put the script above (HtmlClipboard.py) in the python module folder: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages
2. install win32clipboard
3. With the 2 points above you could play with a script like this:

   ```python
   #get CF_Html Clipboard
   import HtmlClipboard #.py script found in github
   if HtmlClipboard.HasHtml():
       # print('there is HTML!!')
       dirty_HTML = HtmlClipboard.GetHtml()
       print(dirty_HTML)
   else:
       print('no html')

   dirty_HTML= clean_HTML #do what you want with it

   #put data to clipboard:
   HtmlClipboard.PutHtml(clean_HTML)
   ```

Bonus:

```
##get CF_TEXT from clipboard
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```